# `preg_match_all()` yields incorrect/null results

Tags: php, regex, serialization, preg-match-all, recursive-regex

**The question**

Why do I get the wrong results?  How can I get the desired results?

**The input file**

```
vulture (wing)
tabulations: one leg; two legs; flying
father; master; patriarch
mat (box)
pedistal; blockade; pilar
animal belly (oval)
old style: naval
jackal's belly; jester    slope of hill (arch)
key; visible; enlightened
```

**The two versions of the code, with issue**

Version 1:

```
<?php
$filename = "fakexample.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$myFile = fread($file, filesize($filename));
//PLEASE NOTE THAT $STARTSAFE IS IN PLACE IN THIS VERSION AND NOT IN THE NEXT
function get_between($startString, $endString, $myFile, $startSafe, $endSafe){
  //CHANGES WILL START HERE
  if($startSafe = 0){
    $startStringSafe = $startString;
  }
  elseif($startSafe = 1){
    $startStringSafe = preg_quote($startString, '/');
  }
  //AND END HERE
  if($endSafe = 0){
    $endStringSafe = $endString;
  }
  elseif($endSafe = 1){
    $endStringSafe = preg_quote($endString, '/');
  }
  //non-greedy match any character between start and end strings. 
  //s modifier should make it also match newlines.
  preg_match_all("/$startStringSafe(.*?)$endStringSafe/m", $myFile, $matches);
  return $matches;
}
$list = get_between("^", ")", $myFile, 0, 1);
foreach($list[1] as $list){
  echo $list."\n";
}
?>
```

This code returns nothing.

Version 2:

```
<?php
$filename = "fakexample.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$myFile = fread($file, filesize($filename));
//PLEASE NOTE THAT $STARTSAFE IS NOT IN PLACE IN THIS VERSION
function get_between($startString, $endString, $myFile, $startSafe, $endSafe){
  //CHANGES START HERE

    $startStringSafe = $startString;



  //AND END HERE
  if($endSafe = 0){
    $endStringSafe = $endString;
  }
  elseif($endSafe = 1){
    $endStringSafe = preg_quote($endString, '/');
  }
  //non-greedy match any character between start and end strings. 
  //s modifier should make it also match newlines.
  preg_match_all("/$startStringSafe(.*?)$endStringSafe/m", $myFile, $matches);
  return $matches;
}
$list = get_between("^", ")", $myFile, 0, 1);
foreach($list[1] as $list){
  echo $list."\n";
}
?>
```

This returns `vulture (wing mat (box animal belly (oval jackal's belly; jester slope of hill (arch`.

**The desired output**

`vulture mat animal belly jackal's belly; jester slope of hill`

**Marked differences**

`vulture **(wing** mat **(box** animal belly **(oval** jackal's belly; jester slope of hill **(arch**`

Comment: You could use http://rubular.com/ to test your regex. Very helpful !

Comment: Maybe because I'm using `file_get_contents()`, there's only one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` means start of subject per default. If you want it to mean start of line, then you will have to use the [`/m` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#~MULTILINE) in your regex wrapper.

Comment: So I basically have to use `/m` instead of `/s`?  I'm getting null results.

Comment: You can combine both flags. That is `/ms`.

Comment: What's strange is, regardless of whether I use `/m` or `/s`, the I get a null result when I use a paramaterized $startString, and I get `vulture (wing mat (box animal belly (oval jackal's belly; jester slope of hill (arch` when I don't.  Neither are correct.  Correct should be `vulture mat animal belly jackal's belly; jester    slope of hill`.  So, it's breaking at the wrong character.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your cumbersome function is all about, neither have you elaborated on your input. But you might want to review the `if` statements. There are assignment expressions within, not comparisons.

Comment: If you have time, I edited for clarity.  The function isn't very long, but the script is kind of bulky I guess.  Hopefully the edited version will be easier.

Comment: `get_between("^", ")"` will cut out to the closing parenthesis, not the opening one you assume to use. Still incorrent assignments.

Comment: I checked that line like 10 times because it was the only thing I could think of, and it never was )....  Then you told me it was that line, and I looked, and it magically was.  Isn't that so strange?  Any idea why the paramaterized version still returns null? :)